# Stop apache and run node server

Tags: node.js, apache, centos

I have a centos 7.9 linux server with whm panel installed. Apache is installed directly on the domain names I created, I don't want to run apache on the subdomain of one domain name. I want to run a node js server. When I say "service httpd stop", they all shut down. What to do?

Comment: Create a vhost for your node.js app and use the proxyPass to forward traffic as reverse proxy to your node app. (Start your node app on a diffrent port then apache)

Answer (score 0):

Network services don't bind themselves to specific hostnames. You have one Apache server running. Any connection to port 80 will connect to that server. Apache then looks at the `host` header in the HTTP request to determine which website to respond with.

If you want one site to use Node.js then you need to pick one of these options:

- Configure Apache to act as a reverse proxy for the Node.js hosted server
- Run the Node.js server on a different computer and point the host name at that computer
- Have multiple network interfaces for the existing computer, with their own IP addresses, configure Apache to listen on one and Node.js to listen on the other, then point the hostnames at the right IP addresses.

(I don't recommend the last one as it is the most fiddly).